# Acts as taggable on: All tags stuck on the same line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts_as_taggable_on in a rails 4.1 app, everything works but displaying the tag cloud results in all the tags being squashed together on one line with no line breaks, how can I fix this?

I'm using the same css as on the gem page

```
.css1 { font-size: 1.0em; }
.css2 { font-size: 1.2em; }
.css3 { font-size: 1.4em; }
.css4 { font-size: 1.6em; }
```

Comment: all the tags are displayed on a single line in the tag cloud

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to put your tags in some kind of grid/column. For example, if you are using bootstrap, in framework_and_overrides.css.scss add:

```
.col-sm-4{
 .css1 { font-size: 1.0em; }
 .css2 { font-size: 1.2em; }
 .css3 { font-size: 1.4em; }
 .css4 { font-size: 1.6em; }
}
```

and in your view, try something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Popular tags</h3>
 </div>

 <div class="panel-body">
  <% tag_cloud( Post.tag_counts_on(:tags), %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
   <%= link_to "<span class='label label-primary'>#{tag}</span>".html_safe, tag_path(tag.name), :class => css_class %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```